# Changing program start address

Tags: arm, embedded, mbed

I've exported mbed_blinky project for keil uvision 5 and i want to develop a program for another board, so I need to change the start address of program. I change the start in IROM1 in options for target window but it doesn't work. It must be defined in somewhere but I can't find it. Can anyone help?

My target is LPC1768

Comment: the start address should be the least of your problems, the peripherals are likely different between targets yes?  esp if they have different rom locations.

Comment: yes, but it's just a header board it doesn't have any modules.what can be a problem?

Comment: another board with the same processor then why would the start address change?  if ti is another board with a different processor then the peripherals and/or core, or both are different, using a different start address raises a flag indicating that.  Why are you thinking you need to change the start address?  lets start there.

Comment: the processor is the same, my board has a boot loader so the programming must be started from 0x2000.

Comment: and the bootloader is not part of the binary nor something you can copy?  there should be a linker script somewhere then, or you can patch up the binary to branch to 0x2000 (add 0x2000 bytes with the first N bytes of that being the vector table if there is one from your 0x2000 entry point.

Answer (score 1):

In uVision, the linker script (or scatter file as Keil refers to it)  is either generated from the target settings that you have tried to change or can be overridden on the linker tab with a "*scatter file*"; it is possible that the mbed export does not generate a uVision *target tab* compatible scatter file or requires settings not available in uVision's basic  target dialog, so is using a custom scatter file.

On the [linker tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq11T.png), check whether or not the *"Use memory layout from target dialog*" is checked or not.  If you want to use the "*Target*" tab settings it must be checked, otherwise the file in the "*Scatter file*" setting on the linker tab is used and you will need to edit that, and check all other settings on teh linker tab are correct for your target..

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I've used mbed in Eclipse/GCC and am less familiar with Keil.  If you want to change target boards/micro's, you are better off doing a new Export from either the online compiler or from mbed-cli tool with the new target selected.  The start address is only one of many things that have to change for a new target.  The files required to compile for the new target are all on the disc inside the mbed-os folder, but when you exported the original project, they helpfully excluded unnecessary files from the project items.  Files are on the disc, just not part of Keil project setup.  You would have to also edit the Device on the options tab and the C/C++ include paths and compiler flags as these relate to specific target.  Then you will need to locate the correct linker file and startup file for the new target. Again, it is easier to just export a new project for the new target.